# Replace Var_dump / Var_exported data in PHP

Tags: php

**My Question**

Is it possible to replace var_dump / var_export data by using str_replace or any other special method in PHP?

for example changing this:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'age' => '21',
    'number' => '45243',
    'anotherNumber' => '32463',
    'anotherAge' => '33',
  ),
)
```

Into this

```
[
  0 => 
  [
    'age' => '21',
    'number' => '45243',
    'anotherNumber' => '32463',
    'AnotherAge' => '33',
  ],
]
```

using a statement like `str_replace('array (', '[', var_export($obj));`

Or something along those lines, i've tried the above statement but it doesnt work

Comment: This question (or similar) has been asked before, and it is not as simple as replacing all  occurrences of `array(` and `)` with `[` and `]`, because a robust, accurate pattern will have to factor in values that may hold these characters.  Getting this wrong will result in mangling the data.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's impossible. Because there can be '(' or ')' in array keys or values, and it will be replaced as well. Better to build own function using recursion with proper formatting

e.g:

```
function myDump($arr) {

    if (is_scalar($arr)) {
        echo var_export($arr);
        return;
    }
    if (is_array($arr)) {
        echo '[' . PHP_EOL; 
        $cc = '';
        foreach ($arr as $k => $val) {
            echo $cc, var_export($k), ' => ';
            myDump($val, $level + 1);
            $cc = ',' . PHP_EOL;
        }
        echo '],', PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$arr = array (
  array (
    'age' => '21',
    'number' => '45243',
    'anotherNumber' => '32463',
    'anotherAge' => '33',
  ),
);

echo '<pre>';
myDump($arr);
echo '</pre>';
```

output will be:

```
[
0 => [
'age' => '21',
'number' => '45243',
'anotherNumber' => '32463',
'anotherAge' => '33'],
],
```

This is just an example, amend it for your needing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you have to give the "return" parameter to var_export.

Like so: `echo str_replace('array (', '[', var_export($obj, true));`

Further reading: http://php.net/manual/de/function.var-export.php

str_replace can also take arrays as the first two parameters. So you can handle multiple replace operations in one call.

Like so: `echo str_replace(['array (', ')'], ['[', ']'], var_export($obj, true));`

However it should be stated out that this will replace all occurrences of ')' with ']'. So if you use braces in some strings of your array the data would be manipulated.

Comment: Hey thanks your answer has helped a lot, i've read through and made the changes, because i set the return parameter to true it now returns a value instead of printing it out, so i had to echo the line of code, and now all works well thanks for this!

Comment: The question was. "Is it possible" not "Is it reliable"

Comment: @mickmackusa why is this not a reliable method?

Comment: Because you can have strings in you array like so: `['a string with ) ']` This would produce `[ 0 => 'a string with ] '` after applying the str_replace function

Comment: @CorneliusFillmore Ah i see.. this makes sense to me and thanks for mentioning i overlooked this possibility